# LibSVM Data Formatting

Tags: libsvm, weka

I cannot get Weka to accept this LibSVM file. I've formatted feature sets using LibSVM before with no problems but for some reason it won't take this file. Here is the specific error:

```
Unable to determine structure as libsvm: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Here is a sample from the file itself:

```
0 0:640 1:71 2:40.11 3:177 4:0 5:0.56 6:0 7:5 8:2 9:0 10:1 11:0.0 12:0.0 13:0 14:0.03 15:0.0 16:0 17:1 18:1 19:0
0 0:423 1:41 2:36.61 3:112 4:0 5:0.00 6:0 7:5 8:2 9:0 10:1 11:0.0 12:0.0 13:0 14:0.02 15:0.0 16:0 17:1 18:1 19:0
0 0:534 1:65 2:38.92 3:167 4:0 5:0.00 6:0 7:3 8:2 9:0 10:1 11:0.0 12:0.0 13:0 14:0.0 15:0.0 16:0 17:1 18:1 19:0
1 0:3841 1:142 2:18.66 3:761 4:0 5:0.26 6:0 7:2 8:2 9:0 10:1 11:0.0 12:0.0 13:0 14:0.0 15:0.0 16:0 17:0 18:0 19:0
1 0:486 1:20 2:15.27 3:131 4:1 5:1.53 6:0 7:2 8:1 9:0 10:1 11:0.0 12:0.0 13:1 14:0.0 15:0.0 16:0 17:1 18:1 19:0
0 0:142 1:12 2:29.27 3:41 4:0 5:0.00 6:0 7:5 8:3 9:0 10:1 11:0.0 12:0.0 13:1 14:0.0 15:0.0 16:0 17:0 18:0 19:0
0 0:614 1:21 2:14.0 3:150 4:0 5:0.67 6:0 7:3 8:4 9:0 10:3 11:0.0 12:0.0 13:0 14:0.01 15:0.0 16:0 17:0 18:0 19:0
1 0:734 1:45 2:33.09 3:136 4:0 5:0.00 6:0 7:2 8:2 9:0 10:1 11:0.0 12:0.0 13:1 14:0.0 15:0.0 16:0 17:1 18:1 19:0
```

I don't understand why it is not accepting this file. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices should start at 1, not 0. Add 1 to all your indices and it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks! Doh! I knew it had to be something stupid like that.